# Apache stop all incoming request & wait till all the traffic of this server done

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i am trying to write a shell script that will automatically update my server

```
  #!/bin/bash
  if[build_server_response=true];then

    ## STOP ALL INCOMING REQUEST/TRAFFIC ON THIS SERVER
    ## WAIT TILL ALL THE EXISTING REQUEST/TRAFFIC IS DONE 

    #DETACH FROM LOAD BALANCE R
    aws elb deregister-instances-from-load-balancer

    perform_server_update;

    #ATTACH BACK TO LOAD BALANCE R
    aws elb register-instances-with-load-balancer
  if
```

How can I achieve this what are the commands for that

```
     ## STOP ALL INCOMING REQUEST/TRAFFIC ON THIS SERVER
     ## WAIT TILL ALL THE EXISTING REQUEST/TRAFFIC IS DONE 
     ## OR
     ## SHIFT ALL REQUEST/TRAFFIC  FROM THIS SERVER TO ANOTHER SERVER
```

So that none of the user get any error

I am even using sticky session of 60 seconds in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it by using "Connection Draining" feature of amazon aws

source:

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2014/03/20/elastic-load-balancing-supports-connection-draining/